# android: Using Gravity.Start or Gravity.End before api-level 14

Tags: android, gravity, hebrew

due to problems with Hebrew language (RTL) inside EditText in Some Samsung devices on some ROMs:
when the gravity is set to the Right or Left, the cursor is stuck on the right side of the EditText and won't move along with the inserted text.

Gravity.Start solved this for api levels >=14.

is there a way to use the Gravity.Start and Gravity.End attributes before api-level 14?

Thanks,
Raz

Comment: Ask whoever created your ROM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [stated here](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/huuJd8iVVXY) -

Although the constants are only defined in API 14 [0], they are backward compatible because

1. They're inlined at compile time
2. They're functionally equivalent to LEFT and RIGHT on earlier devices because of their least-significant bytes.

Comment: how does this then relate to Android Studio's NOTE as shown here: http://i.imgur.com/b35J5gC.png . we should add BOTH attributes but then the note on the bottom seems to indicate only for right/end . ?!

Answer (score 3):

There are `GravityCompat.START` and `GravityCompat.END`.

See [GravityCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/GravityCompat.html).